# Задача о рюкзаке с мемоизацией

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Реализую алгоритм решения задачи о рюкзаке с мемоизацией.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int knapsack(const vector<int> *weights, const vector<int> *values, int n, int i, int j){
    int value;
    int **v = new int *[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        v[i] = new int[n];
    //Заполнение массива v начальынми значениями
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int k = 0; i < j; k++){
            if(i == 0 || k == 0)
                v[i][k] = 0;
            else
                v[i][k] = -1;
        }

    if(v[i][j] < 0){
        if(j < weights[i])
            value = knapsack(weights, values, n, i - 1, j);
        else
            value = max(knapsack(weights, values, n, i - 1, j),
                    values[i] + knapsack(weights, values, n, i - 1, j - weights[i]);
        v[i][j] = value;
    }
    return v[i][j];
}

int main(){

}
```

Мне здесь не нравится все. Слишком много аргументов функции: число имеющихся вещей `n` и, может быть, было бы удобнее вместо двух векторов `weights` и `values` использовать один. Не нравится способ передачи этих векторов в функцию: чтобы стек не забивался, я передаю их по константной ссылке, но из-за этого внутри функции возникли ошибки. Таблица `v` в каждом экземпляре функции при рекурсивном вызове создается заново и имеет разные размеры. Это плохо.

Как можно улучшить эту функцию?

Еще у меня непонимание вот в чем. Каким образом здесь используется мемоизация, если не видно, как возвращаются предвычисленные значения из таблицы? Мы сначала строим таблицу, а потом возвращаем нужное значение. Или условие `if(v[i][j] < 0)` как раз и гарантирует нам, что нужное значение будет браться из предвычисленой таблицы, а не вычисляться каждый раз заново?

Привожу исходный псевдокод алгоритма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Knapsack{
private:
    vector<int> weights;
    vector<int> values;
    int n, w;
    int **v;
public:
    Knapsack(vector<int> wt, vector<int> val, int n, int cap){
        // Сохранение переданных векторов, числа элементов и вместимости ранца
        weights.assign(wt.begin(), wt.end());
        values.assign(val.begin(), val.end());
        this->n = n;
        this->w = cap;
        // Создание таблицы мемоизации и заполнение начальными значениями
        v = new int * [n];
        for(int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
            v[i] = new int [w];
        // Инициализирование таблицы
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < w; j++)
                v[i][j] = -1;
        // Инициализирование нулями первой строки и первого столбца
        for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            v[0][i] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            v[i][0] = 0;
    }
    ~Knapsack(){
        for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            delete[] v[i];
        delete[] v;
    }
    int knapsack_solver(int i, int j);
    int solve();
};

int Knapsack::knapsack_solver(int i, int j){
    int value;
    if(v[i][j] < 0){
        if(j < weights[i])
            value = knapsack_solver(i - 1, j);
        else
            value = max(knapsack_solver(i - 1, j),
                        values[i] + knapsack_solver(i - 1, j - weights[i]));
        v[i][j] = value;
    }
    return v[i][j];
}

int Knapsack::solve(){
    return knapsack_solver(n, w);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. В книге же написано массив v должен быть глобальным, то есть создаваться один раз и передаваться как параметр.
2. Векторы вы передаете по указателю, а не по ссылке.
3. Если вас смущает количество параметров засуньте их в структуру и передавайте указатель на нее, ну или сделайте их глобальными.
4. Вот это никогда не закончится:

   ```
   for(int k = 0; i < j; k++){
      if(i == 0 || k == 0)
         v[i][k] = 0;
      else
         v[i][k] = -1;
   }
   ```

Мой вам совет сначала добейтесь чтобы код работал правильно, а затем его улучшайте, думайте про количество параметров и прочее. Как говорил великий Дейкстра, - "Преждевременная оптимизация - враг любого проекта".

И еще не большой совет: не стоит называть переменные одинаковыми именами, такой код очень трудно понимать.

Comment: Пытаюсь исправить программу. В конце ОП-поста добавил новый код и буду дальше его улучшать. Хорошо ли я начал проектировать класс?

Comment: @typemoon Должен работать

Comment: Не работает. Падает. https://ideone.com/KmRwtc

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас много параметров, разделите их на постоянную и переменную часть.

Заведите класс, постоянную часть (`weights`, `values` и мемоизацию, кажется) положите в класс, рекурсивную функцию превратите в приватный метод, и передавайте только `i`, `j`.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что это будет за класс. Почему метод приватный? Как он будет работать? Как создается класс, что передается в конструктор кроме i и j?

Comment: Добавил еще один скрин наверх. Там написано, что массив v инициализируется начальными значениями, и в этом процессе участвуют переменные i и j. А как это реализовать, если эти переменные каждый раз передаются в функцию при рекурсивном вызове? Как-то напутано в книге. Непонятно, как все это реализуется на языках типа C++.

Comment: Вот такая программа крашится. https://ideone.com/KmRwtc